# Plugins using a (assembly) reference to the host Application

Tags: .net, architecture, plugins, mef

I'm developing an application which i want to be expandable using plugins.

Here at SO i found many suggestions on using MEF which is a simple solution to load the plugins DLLs from a directory.
The common approach would be to setup a base class or interface that plugins must inherit/implement and include that class/interface in a library assembly, i.e PluginBase.dll, that both the application and the plugin will reference.

I have two problems using this tecnique:

1. Shared classes

   There will be classes in the main application that should also be available to the plugins.

   The obvious solution is to move them to the common library assembly, still i don't think it's correct to have thoose classes in PluginBase.dll as they're not related to the plugin architecture.

   I could also make a separate DLL for such classes but that would mean that a second dll should be loaded at startup and included in the plugin for development (not really a problem, but i'd prefer newbies to just add a single reference).
2. Members visibility

   This is the real problem: I'm also writing internal plugins that have more control on the application.

   Since any member of internally-used type would require its class to be moved to PluginBase.dll, I had to inherit a base plugin class in 2 other types (normal and internal plugin) and only put the base and normal classes on PluginBase.dll. But actually it's worse because the plugin can have a GUI or not so at the end of the day everything is doubled... this is getting too messy.

**The solution (is it?)**

I discovered that i can directly add a reference to the main Application in the Plugin project and doing so i can easily access any class. But also, hiding class/members is just a matter or using the *internal* visibility specifier.
No interfaces to implement, no other assemblies to load at startup, it just seems quicker, simpler and more effective.

Are there side-effects i should be aware of using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is in the same sense as this: http://rickrat.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-mef-to-link-view-model-locator-and-load-assembly-uis-dynamically/
[image]

The app and the plugin do not need to know about each other, they only need to reference the shared contract assembly.

Word of caution: Make sure your shared contracts dll is signed with a public key, because if MEF finds it in the addin folder (which it could be) it would try to load it twice. Having a public key it checks it against what is already loaded and does not load it again.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that article. I can't find how this solves my problems (1) and (2) tough. Could you point out where should i look?

Comment: What I'm saying is don't reference host app, reference shared dll that both can reference.

Comment: I understood what you mean, but that was more or less my initial approach: a shared dll. I'm considering the host reference idea to solve a couple of problems, and of course i'm open to other solutions.The point is, your answer don't seem to solve the 2 problems and if you just mean that referencing the host is a bad idea it's fine but i'd like to know why.

Comment: Why would be because then you have a direct dependency on the host app. Also, consider postbuild.bat files to move the dll to the proper plugin folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, then you need to see [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) Its a nice one , may be it will helps you for making Plugin based application.

Comment: I know there are other frameworks to do composition, but i'm looking for opinions on this possible solution.

Comment: In question you mentioned that , Adding reference of main application to plugin, but this solution is not fit in Plugin based application, because in this solution you are decreasing flexibility to make plugin.  So from the design point of of view this solution is improper,

Comment: IMHO there's nothing wrong if the Plugin depends on the main application, the plugin is made for it so it's natural if there is such dependence. Also, it seems much more flexible because i can easily access my app classes. Can you explain why you said that it "decreases flexibility"?

Comment: Ideally speaking,plugin must only know parts of host that can be used by it, because giving whole control to drive application is wrong as per architecture. Generally Host defines one contract which describes What and how plugin can use host functionality,plugin developer does not have to worry about host environment, because everything will be depends on contract(Guideline) given by Host.Lets take an example, if plugin references main application, plugin will  violate host application environment. So thumb rule of plugin based application is Host environment shouldn't be disturbed by plugin